# how to open a tab (tabpane) and scroll to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click on a link and open a tab in the current page ( review) and scroll to it. I don't want to use the hash in url.....

This is my code for click on link:

```
$('#openReview').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#review"]').tab('show');
    document.getElementById("review").scrollIntoView();
});
```

The problem is : I have to click twice!!!

First: it make the tab active ( the second tab) -> then second click scroll to it.

How can I make it to work only with one click? :)

Comment: please post also your HTML code

Comment: @mike_t I reproduced my example in a plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/pm9faq8SmaLzeLDOoEtP?p=preview

Comment: i posted an answer based on your plnkr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
$('#openReview').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#review"]').tab('show');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".tabs-widget").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

If you have more elements with class `tabs-widget` i suggest you add an id to this element instead and reference it in the `scrollTop`. You can change the scroll animation duration in the code (my example is 2 sec)

**EDIT**

In fact, your code will work if you use an id on the wrapping section of the tabs instead of using #reviews. The reason being is that it takes some miliseconds for tab("show") to execute and meanwhile the element #reviews is not in the view, so can't be immediately scrolled to.

```
$('#openReview').on('click', function () {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#review"]').tab('show');
    document.getElementById("tabs_widget").scrollIntoView();
});

...
<!-- in you HTML -->
<section class="tabs-widget" id="tabs_widget">
```